# How prevent retrieve a child in same parent node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want to read all **usernames from users** parent node, because I'm using **search feature** in my app (if provided searchActive: true child in users node). But **email need to be reachable only by owner.**

I have just tried like below, but I'm still getting email. I'm worried about security not only email, What I'm missing and How Can I organize all of them?

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid": {
         ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
         ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
          "username": {
             ".validate": "
              !root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
               root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
               },
          "email": {
              ".read": "auth.uid == 'facebook:'+$uid || auth.uid == $uid"
               }
         }
    },
    "usernames": {
          ".write": "auth !== null",
          ".read": "auth !== null"
    },
```

Comment: @Arescet I know what means soflow, this is Firebase security script, I have explained above what I have encountered when I used that. Do not advice about irrelevant topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the reason why you can still access email is because [rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade) meaning when you set read to true for the parent node all the children can also be read. In your case:

```
"users": {
  //Read is being set to true here for everything in this node
  ".read": "auth !== null",
  "$uid": {
     ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
     //This will be ignored, since read was allowed already
     ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      "username": {
         ".validate": "
          !root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).exists() ||
           root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
           },
      "email": {
          //This will be ignored, since read was allowed already
          ".read": "auth.uid == 'facebook:'+$uid || auth.uid == $uid"
           }
     }
},
"usernames": {
      ".write": "auth !== null",
      ".read": "auth !== null"
},
```

I suggest you take some time to read all the documentation about firebase security. It can really help you avoid situations like this and perhaps give you some idea's about implementing a good security for your case.

A possible solution is to use a seperate username node where you store all the usernames for your search feature. You can use the rules to make sure everyone can read it but only the owner of a specific username can change it.